# Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please seniors, I have dataframes with four columns. I want to add another column, but kept getting error. I have tried to use df["] = dkdkdkddk. This doesn't work. Below is the code.
How else can I add the column please

```
def eval_func(chromosome):
F = chromosome.getCompiledCode()
fit = []
for version in range(len(numberOfversion)):
    spectrum = FaultVersionsDict[str(numberOfversion[version])]
    EP = spectrum[:, 0]
    EF = spectrum[:, 1]
    NP = spectrum[:, 2]
    NF = spectrum[:, 3]
    spectrum[:, 4] = (EF+NP)/(EP+EF+NP+NF) #This is generating error. please help
```

Sequel to the first comment, I am updating the post.

The sample of the current dataframe is like

```
EP EF NP NF
30 40 10 20
20 40 20 20`
.`
.
.`
.
60 10 20 10
```

This is a csv files and I have up to 200 csv files all together.
I just want to create another column after NF to make it the fifth column. The problem is that I have tried all the ways to add new columns, but kept getting error.

The error is always `IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4`

Comment: provide a sample of the current dataframe before the addition of the new column, moreover, give a sample of the data you try to add in order to reproduce the issue (all of the global variables like numberOfversion, FaultVersionsDict, and chromosome.getCompiledCode()

Comment: @TomerS , I have updated the post sir.

Comment: provide an actual dataframe with data so it will be possible to reproduce the issue. Moreover, just to verify you want to add (EF+NP)/(EP+EF+NP+NF) as a new column?

Comment: Yes sir. Just to add (EF+NP)/(EP+EF+NP+NF) as a new column.

Comment: please notice you don't need EP = spectrum[:, 0] for example, as long as you have it already as a column name. please look at my answer

Comment: @TomerS I have solved the problem using your suggestion sir. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the sample DF:

```
import pandas as pd

EP = [30, 20, 60]
EF = [40, 40, 10]
NP = [10, 20, 20]
NF = [20, 20, 10]
spectrum = pd.DataFrame(EP, columns=["EP"])
spectrum['EF'] = EF
spectrum['NP'] = NP
spectrum['NF'] = NF
```

after that, you can simply do that (without the loop):

```
spectrum['Calculation'] = (spectrum.EF+spectrum.NP)/(spectrum.EP+spectrum.EF+spectrum.NP+spectrum.NF)
```

Comment: Thanks sir. But I have been using this when I use only one csv file. But this is still getting error while using multiple csv files.

Comment: you can create list of df, each time you read a csv add it to the list, merge and then apply the function

Comment: Thanks sir. I have solved it.

Comment: please accept and upvote my answer if it helped

Comment: I did, but its like I am not qualified yet to upvote an answer